# input/output error when rebooting

Tags: centos, web-server

My web server is continuously crashing. When I log in, via SSH, to reboot it I get an input/output error. I can't reboot and I have to call the host. They host checked and it is not a problem with the HDD. What else could it be and how can I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2):

If they haven't already done so, try running fsck which will check the consistency of the file system.  Do you get this error when trying to do any other tasks, maybe `ps -e`?  There is some sort of communication error going on